# JSON Unterminated object at character android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I have a `.json` file that contains JSON data. I created this file by simply Ctrl + C and Ctrl + V (from server output) Here's part of my file

```
[{
    "ID": "109",
    "objectTypeID": "1",
    "names": [{
        "ID": 1,
        "code": "lt",
        "value": "Trak\u0173 salos pilis "
    }, {
        "ID": 2,
        "code": "en",
        "value": "Trakai Island Castle"
    }, {
        "ID": 3,
        "code": "ru",
        "value": "\u0422\u0440\u0430\u043a\u0430\u0439\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0437\u0430\u043c\u043e\u043a"
    }, {
        "ID": 4,
        "code": "de",
        "value": "Kasteel van Trakai"
    }],
    "descriptions": [{
        "ID": 1,
        "code": "lt",
        "value": "<div><strong>Paslap\u010di\u0173 m\u0117g\u0117jams ir ie&scaron;kotojams<\/strong><\/div>\r\n\r\n<div>Tiems, kurie domisi istorija, kurie m\u0117gsta paslaptingas vietoves, \u012f Trakus atkeliauti b\u016btina. Trak\u0173 pilis yra vienas labiausiai turist\u0173 lankom\u0173 objekt\u0173 Lietuvoje......"
    }]
}]
```

I have saved this file with `utf-8` encoding
As you can see there are lot of `Unicode Characters` and html elements like `<div>`, `<strong>` and so on....
Now I want to parse this file. Here's my java/android code

```
private String getJSONString(File file){
        try {
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            return new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

private void object_parser(File file){
    String jsonString = getJSONString(file);
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    try {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
            Log.d("OBJECTS_LIST_AAA", jsonArray.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("OBJECTS_LIST_ERROR", e.getMessage()); // print error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and  I get this error `Unterminated object at character 5641 of [{"ID":"109","objectTypeID":"1","names":[{"ID":1,"code":"lt","value":"Trak\u0173 salos pilis "},......`
I think that formating is missing in this file.

Comment: Can you post that Json fully or add some link to refer that.

Comment: here's the link to the json http://demo.ltic.lt/mobile/index.php?module=tourism&action=objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Every `"Restaurant "Avilys""` like data are invalid, You have to replace all of them with `"Restaurant Avilys"` as a single String value quoted with only two quotation marks. There are many similar cases like these as well. And note that the part you posted is clearly valid and can be parsed easily, Here is no such errors.